# How to replace every instance of a string on a page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to replace every instance of `®` on every page with `<sup>®</sup>` but I can't seem to hit every single one. I currently have:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var replaced = $('body').html().replace('®','<sup>®</sup>');
            $('body').html(replaced);
        });
```

but it's only replacing the first occurance of the `®`. How can I get it to do all of them?

Comment: Use a regex to capture all instances: `replace(/®/g, '<sup>®</sup>');`. Also note that replacing content in this manner can lead to a FOUC. A much better solution would be to replace the content at the source, either in the HTML directly or in the database the content is being read from.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i don't have the data coming from a db, but what do you mean in the HTML directly?

Comment: Open .html file, find/replace the character, save .html file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use replaceAll function

```
var replaced = $('body').html().replaceAll('®','<sup>®</sup>');
```

The difference between replaceAll() and replace():

If search argument is a string, replaceAll() replaces all occurrences of search with replaceWith , while replace() only the first occurence.

If search argument is a non-global regular expression, then replaceAll() throws a TypeError exception.

Comment: excellent, i missed that! this works, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: No problem!
You are welcome :)